# Imap mail not working properly

Tags: php, imap

I have the following code in my project. The issue is that the message (body of the email) is not displaying properly.

```
--37cd8764df1f86bc509d0994d83f1d26 Content-type: text/plain;charset="iso-8859-1" Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit hello --37cd8764df1f86bc509d0994d83f1d26 Content-type: text/html;charset="iso-8859-1" Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit hello --37cd8764df1f86bc509d0994d83f1d26--
```

It is showing the above result in email. Where "hello" is the body text.

The other issue is that if I attach the file the body is not shown and the attachment is sent properly. I have the following code.

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
?>
<?php
include("validation/lg_check.php");
?>
<?php
$to1=trim($_POST['txt_to']);
$sub=trim($_POST['txt_sub']);
$msg=$_POST['txt_body'];
$_SESSION['err_mail']=array();

if(empty($to1))
{
$_SESSION['err_mail']['to']="Please Enter The Recepient";
exit;
}
$imap = imap_open("{myserver}", $_SESSION['user']);
$return_path = $_SESSION['user'];
$to = $to1;
$subject = $sub;

# Get a random 32 bit number using time() as seed.

$boundary=md5(date('r',time()));
$message=' --'.$boundary."\n";
$message .='Content-type: text/plain;charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n";
$message .='Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'."\n\n";
$message .=$msg."\n";
$message .='--'.$boundary."\n";
$message .='Content-type: text/html;charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n";
$message .='Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'."\n\n";
$message .=$msg."\n";
$message .='--'.$boundary.'--';

if(isset($_FILES['file_upload']) && !empty($_FILES['file_upload']))
{
$fnm=time()."_".$_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
$tmp_file=$_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
$file_upload=move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,"upload/".$fnm);

}

if($file_upload)
{
# Define the attachment section
# Open a file
$file_name="upload/".$fnm;
$file = fopen( $file_name, "r" );
if( $file == false )
{
echo "Error in opening file";
exit();
}
# Read the file into a variable
$size = filesize("upload/".$fnm);
$content = fread( $file, $size);
# encode the data for safe transit
# and insert \r\n after every 76 chars.
$encoded_content = chunk_split( base64_encode($content));
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=".$fnm." ";
$headers .= "name=".$fnm."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;";
$headers .= "filename=".$fnm."\r\n\n";
$headers .= "$encoded_content\r\n";
$headers .= "--$num--";
}       

# Send email now
$retval = imap_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers, $return_path);
if( $retval == true )
{
echo "Message sent successfully...";
/* print $header;
print $message;
echo '<br>';
print $to;
echo '<br>';
print $subject;
echo '<br>';
print $message;
echo '<br>';
print $fnm; */
}
else
{
echo "Message could not be sent...";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send multiple encodings within just one mail body, you first must tell the the client that you do so and what your boundaries to split actually are.

So, before starting with the multiple message bodies, you must wrap that in to a "Content-type: multipart/alternative" which has a parameter: "boundary="---your boundary---":

```
$message='Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
     boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
```

And you need to terminate each and every line by CR and LF !!!
And Headers need that twice to split off the body.

You should really read the RFC for mail headers, it's annoying, I know, but sending out badly formatted e-mails is as well. There are more mail-clients out there than MS Outlook !

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. But I am new to php , so will you please update the regions which causes the error.

Comment: This is not a php problem, the mail header is set up wrong. Your proper php code is generating invalid mail headers.